# How can I get around memory problems in R?

Tags: r, memory, spatial

I'm applying the function image(cp) to gps data but when I do so it throws up the following error

```
Error in image(as(x, "SpatialGridDataFrame"), ...) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'image': Error: cannot allocate vector of size 12.3 Mb
```

The SpatialPointsDataFrame of my relocation gps data has two columns. One with the coordinates, the other with the ID of the animal.

I'm running it on a 32 bit system with 4 gigs of RAM.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Install more memory? But seriously now, please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: R might not be using all of the memory it can. First clean your workspace with `rm`, then take a look at `?memory.limt` to see how to check how much RAM is alotted to R and how to request more.

Answer (score 1):

One way that might work with no thinking required:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(cp)
image(r)
```

But, you say `cp` is "gps data" so it's not at all clear why this would be imageable.

One thing you can do is plot it:

```
plot(cp)
```

That will work for a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. If you want to create an image from this somehow you'll need to specify some details.